# How to decide which is the numerator in F test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose we have two samples of size 20,

the first, we have sample standard deviation of 50

the second , we have sample standard deviation of 100

If we want to test

$H_{0}: \sigma^{2}_{1}=\sigma^{2}_{2}$

we can form

$$F=\frac{S_{2}^{2}}{S_{1}^{2}}$$

and compare to the $F_{19,19}$ distribution.

If we do one direction we get $F=0.25$ and $p=0.998$

if we do the other direction we get $F=4$ and $p=0.002$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the two-sided alternative $F$-test for equality of variance, the rejection region includes both the upper and lower tails of the $F$-distribution.  So for example, to test:

\begin{eqnarray*}
H_{0:}\text{ }{\sigma_{1}^{2}}=\sigma_{2}^{2} &&& \text{vs.} &&& H_{1}:\sigma_{1}^{2}\ne{\sigma_{2}^{2}}
\end{eqnarray*}

You reject $H_{1}$ if:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{s_{2}^{2}} & \ge & F_{\alpha/2}(n_{1}-1,\,n_{2}-1)
\end{eqnarray*}

OR if:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{s_{1}^{2}}{s_{2}^{2}} & \le & \frac{1}{F_{\alpha/2}(n_{2}-1,\,n_{1}-1)}
\end{eqnarray*}

So it doesn't matter which statistic is in the numerator.  When you calculate the $p$-value associated with the upper-rejection region, you need to be sure to subject the probability you calculated from 1.  So in your specific example, the probability associated with the rejection region at the top of the $F$-distribution is given by:  $1-0.998 = 0.002$.  This matches the probability at the lower tail.